# Where does one go for libgdx documentation

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently trying to find out about ray casting in libgdx with bullet but there is 0 documentation that I find (Documentation I can interpret at least) The wiki Has nothing on the subject can anyone point me towards some info on the subject?

Comment: [Did you try google?](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ray+casting+in+libgdx+with+bullet&oq=ray+casting+in+libgdx+with+bullet&gs_l=hp.3...164.164.1.341.1.1.0.0.0.0.97.97.1.1.0....0...1c.1.49.hp..1.0.0.V1kiHIbiBQw&biw=1532&bih=856&dpr=1&cad=cbv&sei=Q9TWU4eHB4OkigLHhICYDw)

Comment: Nothing on the first 3 pages to what you linked me to did me any good.

Comment: really, because link 2 I see if a giant github wiki about using bullet.

Comment: And that is not what i need... *Doesn't have the info im looking for*

Comment: Not sure how its off-topic as far as i could tell im clearing asking for where to find something to help me with something but okay.. Glad to know clear questions are not welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Bullet documentation. The implementations in Java/LibGDX follow the same structures and rules as their C++ counterparts.

I can't give any specific links about ray casting as I've no experience with bullet. But any tutorials or documentation for the original should be very easily translatable to LibGDX.

Comment: Ill try that *From what i see it looks 10x harder to understand xD*

Comment: From the few things I looked at it, it seemed like a very complex subject.